# Regex extract string and find highest number from Google Sheet column

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I need to find the latest internal code in a long google sheet, so i know the next number to use in a equipment database... Im new to Regex.

My data looks like this:

```
chggpr-001
chggpr-001
chggpr-001
chggpr-001
chggpr-001
chggpr-001
chggpr-001
chgaa-001
chgaa-001
chgaa-001
chgaa-001
chgaa-001
chgaa-001
chgaa-001
bataa-001
chgusb-001
camacc-015
camacc-016
lensfe-002
vidmon-002
lensfe-003
lensfe-004
cam-003
```

let's say i input the string "camacc" into field B1, i want B2 to return 017, because thats the next number of that code available. This way i know i need to add the new items to that number..

Right now i'm walking blindly, but this regex seems to work in the editor: `camacc\-(\d+)`

In google sheets: `=arrayformula(MAX(0+iferror(regexextract(B2:B580, "chggpr\-(\d+)"))))`
that does not work...

Any tips on how to regex out the string based on cell input, then get the max value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
=TEXT(MAX(INDEX(--IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,B1&"-(\d+)"))+1)),"000")
```

- 

[image]

Comment: That works like a charm :) is it easy to add another range to the same formula, so it checks two different rows, and still finds the max?

Comment: now the sample is looking at Column A. you mean to add lets say Column C into the mix as well?!

Comment: Exactly. Im thinking about splitting my DB into multiple sheets.. so yes.

Comment: Well just replace `A:A` part in the formula with `{A:A;C:C}`

Comment: Aha, my ( ) did not work. Enter curly braces..